# Google Cast iOS sample app not scanning for devices

Tags: ios, google-cast

Trying to use this sample app provided by Google: https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios

It is not asking to connect with my Chromecast, or even scanning for receiver devices. There is only the "Cast Video" button that alerts "Not Connected - Please connect to Cast device" when clicked. I understand there is a whitelisting/registration process for styled and custom media receiver apps, but there is supposed to be a default media receiver app built into the Chromecast that I should be able to use right away. How can I make it scan for devices?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions for setting up that app? Unless you use your own App Id or you update the sample to use the default app id, it won't find any device; it is doing the scanning. In addition, please use the GitHub's issue tracker to ask questions about that and other cast samples if you run into any issues when trying to run them.

Comment: The value for kReceiverAppID is set to "kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID" by default (the readme is not accurate). From your response it sounds like this is not actually the default app id, and I've pored over the setup instructions and can't find anything saying what the default app ID should be. What is the default app ID?

Comment: That is indeed the default receiver's id, so if that is already there, that part is correct. If you want to see a nice UX compliant sample for iOS, I strongly suggest using the CastVideos-ios sample; that is kept up to date with all the updates to the cast SDK and is completely maintained. Meanwhile, please open a bug for the other sample on GitHub so we get that tested and updated, if needed (also indicate that the Readme is not accurate); the CastVideos-ios should work, thx.